# Selecting Windows in grub redirects to bootmgr

Tags: 12.04, grub2, dual-boot, windows-7

About a year ago I installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my Lenovo Computer Running Windows 7 using wubi. I selected the OS using bootmgr during startup and everything was fine and dandy.

Then, I attempted to upgrade to 12.04.  The upgrade failed for reasons not relevant to this question, and left me with a 'dead' linux install.  So today I decided to wipe the old and reinstall 12.04 from scratch.  I removed wubi, and created a new partition on my disk.

The install itself went ok, but the grub/bootmgr config is slightly messed up.  When the machine is booting, it first presents me with the Grub startup screen.  If I select linux, the ubuntu installation starts up.

However, if I select windows 7, grub then sends me to the bootmgr o/s selection screen, which lets me choose either windows 7 or the old, dead ubuntu/wubi installation. Win7 starts fine when selected from this menu.

How can I fix the configuration so that grub starts windows directly without sending me to bootmgr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have not cleaned wubi.

1. Boot into Windows
2. Open Add/Remove programs
3. Search for Ubuntu, and uninstall it.
4. Reboot.

That should fix it.